# setText for JTextfield from array

Tags: for-loop, jtextfield, settext

Here is the code
    String[] textfield = new String [8];

```
int a=600;
    int b=100;
    for (int i=0; i<8; ++i) 
    {
        JTextField f = new JTextField(textfield[i]);
        f.setBounds(a, b, 120, 25);
        b+=30;

        panel.add(f);
        if (i==9) a=300; 
        if (i==9) b=10;

        // Why Not Save Action in loop

    }
```

Now, .setText("") Does not appear after typing textfield[5]
I would like to see : textfield[i].setText("Hello 5");

Comment: check out the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your code `textField[i]` is a `String` not a `JTextField`.

Change it as below.

```
JTextField[] textfield = new JTextFeild[8];
int a=600;
    int b=100;
    for (int i=0; i<8; ++i) 
    {
        textField[i] = new JTextField();
        textField[i].setText("My Text");
        textField[i].setBounds(a, b, 120, 25);
        b+=30;

        panel.add(textField[i]);
        if (i==9) a=300; 
        if (i==9) b=10;

        // Why Not Save Action in loop

    }
```

To print the text of `JTextField` you should use `JTextField.getText()` method.

```
print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void      actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //  
        System.out.println("Error");     
        ramSlot2.setSelectedIndex(5); 
        String txt =textfield[5].getText();     
        System.out.println(txt); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy as that: (when i==5)

```
i = 5
textfield[i] = "Hello ";
String str = textfield[i] + i;
f.setText(str);
```

I think that your `textfield[i]` (when i==5) is not initiated

Comment: print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                 {
                //     System.out.println("Error");
                     ramSlot2.setSelectedIndex(5);
                     String txt =textfield[5];
                     
                     
                     System.out.println(txt);
                     
                 }